# How to calculate the light emission spectrum of scintillator(CsI)?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

I want to find some references on describing the physics of scintillation. As we know the lights generated by scintillator through atom activation and de-activation, and each material has a spectrum and its intensity veries with wave length as shown in the figure below. How to calculate the number of lights generated by the scintillator materials and their distribution(light emission spectrum)?
[image]

Comment: You asked this before, the answer was ‘with difficulty’ particularly in general.

Comment: Hi @rfl, the last poster is closed by the website since they think the question is not specific. So I modified the question to make it more specific and clear.

Comment: Hi, @JonCuster. yeah, it's difficulty to handle the problem from first princeples. I didn't find relative refrence but I want to understand it. the last poster was closed, so I post it again.

Comment: @Winston I had looked for your previous question but hadn't found it, thus my comment. Found it, so I removed my comment. Would have been better to simply edit your previous question, but OK, no worries.